# Custom Nav Walker menu - Display category count

Tags: categories, menus, walker

I have a custom walker menu.( See the code below)

I would like to have my nav menu like this:

[image]

Where 495 is the total of the records containing childrens.

Where 42 Number of published articles.

Can someone help me to implement this?
Here is my current custom nav walker code.

```
<?php
class accordion_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
   function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;  
        $count_category = '';
     if($item->object == 'publishings')  { 
        $cat_id = $item->object_id;
        $count_category = get_terms('publishings', 'fields=count');
   }           
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '(' . $count_category  . ')';
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
?>
```

The code that I use for taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'init', 'prowp_publishing_taxonomy' );
function prowp_publishing_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => 'Категории',
        'singular_name'     => 'Категория',
        'search_items'      => 'Найти Категорию',
        'all_items'         => 'Все категории',
        'parent_item'       => 'Родительская категория',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Родительские категории:',
        'edit_item'         => 'Редактировать категорию',
        'update_item'       => 'обновить категорию',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Добавить новую категорию',
        'new_item_name'     => 'Новое название категории',
        'menu_name'         => 'Категории'
    );
    $args =array(
        'labels'       => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'query_var'    => true,
        'rewrite'      => true
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'type', 'publishings', $args );
}
```

Help me please do it.

display my current result:

[image]

Comment: Can you display your current result?

Comment: I'm creating a website on a local server. I can not show it. The result is on the picture below. Digits are not visible but brackets *( )* are visible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably use [`wp_list_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories), which even has parameters for a count, like e.g. `show_count` and `pad_counts`. Additionally it supports custom walkers via the `walker` parameter, but the walker would be based on [`Walker_Category`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker_Category) - [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L933) -, which gives you every additional styling option you want.